# Complex DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, datatemplateselector

I've implemented *CustomDataTemplateSelector* like here: [Implementing Windows Phone 7 DataTemplateSelector and CustomDataTemplateSelector](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector). But in my solution there is only one part that changes through all DataTemplates, other parts of DataTemplates are common:

```
<local:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
    <local:MyTemplateSelector.OneTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
                    <Image Height="60" Width="60" Source="{Binding Photo}"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue1}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue2}">
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyTemplateSelector.OneTemplate>
    <local:MyTemplateSelector.AnotherTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
                    <Image Height="30" Width="60" Source="{Binding Photos[0]}"/>
                    <Image Height="30" Width="60" Source="{Binding Photos[1]}"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue1}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue2}">
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyTemplateSelector.AnotherTemplate>
</local:MyTemplateSelector>
```

Here *Grid1* and *Grid2* are different parts. Is it possible to "split" these DataTemplates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like declare your common part as Resource and bind it to a ContentPresenter:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommonPart">
   <Grid >
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue1}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue2}">
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<local:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
<local:MyTemplateSelector.OneTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
         <Image Height="60" Width="60" Source="{Binding Photo}"/>
      </Grid>
      <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommonPart}" />                
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</local:MyTemplateSelector.OneTemplate>
<local:MyTemplateSelector.AnotherTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
         <Image Height="30" Width="60" Source="{Binding Photos[0]}"/>
         <Image Height="30" Width="60" Source="{Binding Photos[1]}"/>
      </Grid>
      <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommonPart}" /> 
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</local:MyTemplateSelector.AnotherTemplate>
</local:MyTemplateSelector>
```